# Ubuntu doesn’t recognize Wacom Bamboo Eraser

Tags: wacom

I have just connected Wacom Bamboo CTL-470K-RUPL to my Ubuntu 13.04 (up-to-date 10/26/2013). Everything works fine except an eraser. More precisely, nothing happens when I try to use it (even in GIMP with Preferences → Input Devices → Eraser configured).

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-input-wacom
```

doesn’t help either. How should I re-configure my Wacom tablet to enable eraser? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I realized that the pen in Wacom Bamboo CTL-470K-RUPL simply doesn’t have an eraser. Bah, pity on me.

Comment: Ya know ya might want to select this answer as correct